# store.getActions() not returning actions

Tags: reactjs, testing, redux, mocking

I am trying to test if actions are being dispatched correctly. I am using store.getActions(). It is working on one test but not in another.

store.getActions() is not returning any results in the failing test. Simple tests (getByText) works fine on that component with mock-store data.

The below does not work:

```
test('setButtons action dispatched on button click', () => {
  const store = mockStore(initialState);

  const { getByText } = render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <MemoryRouter>
        <Comments />
      </MemoryRouter>
    </Provider>
  );
  
  const button = getByText('Posts')
  fireEvent.click(button);

  const actions = store.getActions();
  const expectedAction = setButtons('Show Comments');
  console.log('Expected Action Comment:', expectedAction);  
  console.log('Actions Comment:', actions);

  expect(actions).toContainEqual(expectedAction);
});
```

```
console.log                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  Expected Action Comment: { type: 'comments/setButtons', payload: 'Show Comments' }                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/features/Comments/__test__/Comments.test.js:90:11)                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                                            
console.log
  Actions Comment: []
```

The below test does work:

```
test('setButtons action dispatched on button click', () => {
  const store = mockStore(initialState);

  const { getAllByText } = render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <MemoryRouter>
        <Posts />
      </MemoryRouter>
    </Provider>
  );
  
  const button = getAllByText('Comments')
  fireEvent.click(button[0]);

  const actions = store.getActions();
  const expectedAction = setButtons('Hide Comments');
  console.log('Expected Action Posts:', expectedAction);  
  console.log('Actions Posts:', actions);

  expect(actions).toContainEqual(expectedAction);
});
```

```
console.log
  Expected Action Posts: { type: 'comments/setButtons', payload: 'Hide Comments' }

  at Object.<anonymous> (src/features/Posts/__test__/Posts.test.js:108:11)

console.log
  Actions Posts: [
    { type: 'comments/setSelectedComments', payload: undefined },
    { type: 'comments/setSelectedCommentsTitle', payload: 'Post 1' },
    { type: 'comments/setButtons', payload: 'Hide Comments' }
  ]
```

Comment: Please provide the code of the `Comments` component. Can't help without seeing the code

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I found the issue last night. I had not set my mock store up correctly.  There was a slight difference in the structure so could not see the actions.

Cheers